# how to find NSMutableArray index

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray

```
arrPersons:
    <__NSArrayM 0x11c3f090>(    
  <__NSArrayM 0x11c28d40>(    
anil kumar,    
(998) 877-6655    
)    
,    
<__NSArrayM 0x11c210e0>(    
sanjeet kumar,    
(963) 830-7128
)

)
```

Now if I have a name "sanjeet kumar", how do I know which index it is in?

Comment: becoz i want to remove "sanjeet kumar" object for nsmutablearray.

Comment: Can u clear your question?

Comment: i have table view and on didselect i am adding these objects in nsmutablearray, now my requirement is if user clicks on cell second time it remove this data from index.@gran33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be array of array,
arrPersons is the main **mutable array** and it contains another NSArray inside it on whose index 0 contains name and index 1 contains phonenumber

```
NSString *stringToRemove = @"sanjeet kumar";
for (NSArray *array in arrPersons)
{
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:stringToRemove])
    {
        [arrPersons removeObject:array];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// arr is the NSMutableArray
int index = 0;
for (NSArray *array in arr)
{
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"sanjeet kumar"])
    {
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0 ; i< arrPersons.count; i ++)
{
  NSArray *tempArray = [arrPersons objectAtIndex:i];
  if([tempArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@"sanjeetKumar"])
{
    //Remove this object From Array
      break:
}

}
```